# How to Set SSIS Password for FTP Exchange

Tags: ssis, ftp, passwords

I am trying to build an SSIS package that moves some FTP files around. When I set a password and click "test connection" I get a success dialog. However, when I click OK to save the connection string and then execute the step it fails. When I go back to check the connection string, the password field is blank again.

The protection level is currently set to `EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey`.

**How can I save the password so that the package can be executed later with a SQL Server job?**

[image]

Comment: Weird, haven't experienced that.  Sure, after the FTP Connection is initially setup and tested, if you go back and reopen the FTP Connection Manager you have to reenter the password as any task using it will fail.  What's the specific error it's giving you?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is use Project parameter and expression.(SSIS 2008 is call config file)